# Jenkins won't send email notifications (Email ext-plugin)

Tags: jenkins

Plugin Email Extension Plugin V2.104

Console output:

```
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Inside my job I have configured as:
[image]

And in Manage Jenkins > System I have:

[image]

plus Allowed Domains as `@mydomain.com`

Why does it say "An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients" if I have it defined?

Enabling debug mode outputs this:

```
Checking if email needs to be generated
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
Sending mail from default account using System Admin e-mail address
messageContentType = text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Request made to attach build log
  Collecting change authors...
    build: 8
Adding recipients from trigger recipient list
Successfully created MimeMessage
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
```

Also tried adding `to:` in front of my default recipients but still thinks it's empty.

Update after Accepted Answer:

```
Checking for post-build
Performing post-build step
Checking if email needs to be generated
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
Sending mail from default account using System Admin e-mail address
messageContentType = text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Request made to attach build log
  Collecting change authors...
    build: 45
Adding recipients from project recipient list
Analyzing: to:david@mail.com
Failed to create e-mail address for to:david@mail.com
Adding recipients from trigger recipient list
Analyzing: to:david@mail.com
Failed to create e-mail address for to:david@mail.com
Successfully created MimeMessage
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

So `to:` is not allowed in $DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS, only `cc:` and `bcc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Extended Email Plugin in freestyle jobs can be a bit frustrating at start as its configuration is really complex (as opposed to using it from a pipeline job).

The **Project Recipient List** field you filled up in the plugin configuration page (in the job) is not actually the Recipient List to whom the mail will be sent, but rather a global job parameter that can later be used in multiple triggers configured in the plugin.

Ill expalin: in the plugin configuration page you have an *Advance Settings...* button, clicking it will open more configurations, one of them is the Triggers section:

> **Triggers**: You can add an email trigger by selecting it from the dropdown menu. This will add the trigger to the list of configurable triggers.

These *Triggers* is the only thing the determines to whom the mail will be sent to, for each trigger you add you must set the **Send To** option-and that (and only that) determines who will receive the mail.
By default it is usually set to *Developers* or something alike and not to the *Recipient List*, which means the *Project Recipient List* field in the configuration page has no meaning at all.

To achieve what you want just add the relevant trigger you need, and for that trigger add the *Recipient List* to the 'Send To' options, that will make the plugin send mails to the list you provided in the *Project Recipient List* field.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, You set the $DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS and select the triggers in Jenkins > Manage > System > Extended E-mail Notification, then in each build job you have to go to Post Build Actions, add Editable Email Notification and click Advanced Settings under Content Token Reference (picture in answer) then add Recipient List and inside Advanced... set the recipient list (I used $DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS again).